# Angular 2 Pipe argument fails

Tags: javascript, sorting, angular, pipe, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 and trying to sort my array in a `*ngFor=""`.

Sadly it throws me an error and I don't know why, here is the [related post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/order-a-list/55389/2)

My array of objects looks like this : [image: this]

My pipe looks like this :

```
import {Injectable, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Pipe({ name: 'order-by' })
export class OrderByPipe {
  transform(array, args) {
    return _.sortBy(array, args);
  }
}
```

My *ngFor :

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let user of users | order-by:'likes'" >
```

## Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("

    <ion-list>
            <button ion-item [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let user of users | order-by: 'likes'">
```

Other had the same [problem](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/836). Don't know why it doesn't work ..

Do yu have maybe another pipe to sort arrays ? :) Thank you !

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: May be the Pipe name? I have a similar pipe called `orderBy` that works. Also, I pass in the `args` as an `Array`: `['likes']`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Errors of console are in my question under Error Header (updated)
@Arg0n No name of pipe is in decorator `@Pipe({ name: 'order-by' })` so I think correct. Is your pipe sorting array by child value ? :)

Comment: You've missed out the `implements PipeTransform` in your pipe definition

Comment: @luiswill I'm saying that '-' may not be allowed in name, not that it's not the same in your code.

Comment: I see. Your question doesn't mention `toUpperCase`. Looks like you are using it somewhere and that the error is caused there.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore yeah thank you I forgot it, but sadly didn't correct the error
=> Arg0n Oh yeah you're right, sorry didn't know that, this solved the error ! But pipe is not working now.. I will search around a bit.. thanks !

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah I understand, but looks like it's not because of a functin toUpperCase like mentionned in this [link](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/836).

Comment: Can you add a data example for `array` that causes the error?

Comment: @luiswill Maybe some of your `objects` doesn't have `likes` defined? I do have a `OrderByPipe` that sorts on object values, yes. Tho the code is not written by me and can't seem to find where I got it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Already in my question as an image. Update: the pipe works, but in descending order, I think I should look on the web how to reverse :) Thank you :)

Comment: @Arg0n The pipe works, but in descending order, I think I should look on the web how to reverse :) Thank you !

Comment: @luiswill Try using `.reverse()` on the returned `Array`. `return _.sortBy(array, args).reverse();`.

Comment: @Arg0n Yeah just tried before you commented : `return (_.sortBy(array, args)).reverse();`  .. doesn't work, I will search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem Solved !

So first [arg0n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4074045/arg0n) solved the first problem with the name of the pipe, it should be without `-`.   Thank you very much !

`name: sort-by` becomes `name: sortBy`.

And secondly I searched a javascript function which will sort my array.

My *pipe* was then :

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'orderBy' })
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform{
   transform(arr){
    if(arr === undefined){return null;}
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.likes < b.likes) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.likes > b.likes) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Because of **async** in angular 2, I had to put `if(arr === undefined){return null;}` otherwise it throws an error :

```
Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

Finally in my *template.html* I changed to :

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let user of (users | orderBy)">
```

(I didn't put `(users | orderBy) | async` because my array is no more a FireBaseListObservable, but only an array, so not necessary in my opinion)

Comment: It doesn't seem you are using lodash anymore, so you can probably remove the import. As I said earlier, I have another OrderByPipe that isn't restrained to a hardcoded compare value if you're interested.

Comment: All right thank you, atm I just need a pipe for comparing numbers, thank you very much anyway :) !